# File Chooser settings are automatically overwritten on RHEL8

Tags: directory, gtk, settings, hidden, gnome

I have RHEL8 with GNOME desktop.
I am trying to make the file chooser to show hidden files and directories.
I discovered `gsettings` and `dconf-editor` tools.
Through either of them I can get to `org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser` and request eaither of them to show and/or set the value of the "`show-hidden`" property.

By default show-hidden is false.

`$ gsettings get  org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser show-hidden false` 
Same with the dconf-editor. I can change the value to true. It stays true for some time but when I try to open FileChooser I do not see hidden files or directories. And after I close FileChooser the value is overwritten back to "false".
Is it a bug or there is somethign preventign changes to the desktop configuration?

I tried setting the value through dconf-editor or gsettings.
I was expecting the value to stay permanently changed and the FileChooser to respect it and show hidden files and directories.

Comment: same on arch & xfce